# Django checkbox want to check only the first box

Tags: python, html, django, checkbox, view

another checkbox question. I have items in a list. Each item has a checkbox. What I want to do is to tick the *FIRST* item's checkbox in the list. Right know, it has ticked all checkbox's because of `checked="checked"`.

```
{% for item in items %}
            <tr class="items_table_row">
                    <td><input type="checkbox" name="{{item.pk}}" value="{{item.pk}}" checked="checked"></td>
                    <td>{{item.tiptop_id}}</td><td>{{item.alternative_id}}</td><td>{{item.title}}</td><td>{{item.type}}</td><td>{{item.format}}</td>
                    <td><span id="{{item.pk}}" name="type">{{item.itemstatushistory_set.latest}}</span></td><td>{{item.itemstatushistory_set.latest.date.date|date:"d M Y"}}</td>
                    <td><a href="{% url tiptop.views.edit_item item.client.pk item.pk %}" onclick="return showAddAnotherPopup(this);">Edit</a></td>
            </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the checked property to the second item as such:

```
{% ifequal forloop.counter 2 %} checked="checked"{% endifequal %}
```

The default `forloop.counter` is 1-indexed, or you can specifically use a 0-indexed counter:

```
forloop.counter0
```

Comment: For reference - as of Django 1.2 (or maybe even 1.1), {% ifequal forloop.counter 2 %} can be rewritten as {% if forloop.counter == 2 %}

Answer (score 1):

[The `forloop` variable](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for) set by the Django `{% for %}` tag is your friend here.

Pop this in:

```
{% if forloop.first %} checked="checked"{% endif %}
```

i.e.

```
{% for item in items %}
     <tr class="items_table_row">
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="{{item.pk}}" value="{{item.pk}}"{% if forloop.first %} checked="checked"{% endif %}></td>
        <td>{{item.tiptop_id}}</td><td>{{item.alternative_id}}</td><td>{{item.title}}</td><td>{{item.type}}</td><td>{{item.format}}</td>
        <td><span id="{{item.pk}}" name="type">{{item.itemstatushistory_set.latest}}</span></td><td>{{item.itemstatushistory_set.latest.date.date|date:"d M Y"}}</td>
        <td><a href="{% url tiptop.views.edit_item item.client.pk item.pk %}" onclick="return showAddAnotherPopup(this);">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: ok this worked thanks. One more thing if I wanted to check just the second item in my list. I can't type {% if forloop.second %} so what should I type?

Comment: @Shehzad009: sure, that would be `{% if forloop.counter == 2 %}`. You can see the other capabilities of the `{% for %}` tag in the documentation: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for